# Force Number to parse integer String as Double in Java

Tags: java, generics, numbers

How can I parse a set of numeric strings into a generic array? My whole problem can be reduced to the following:

```java
static <T extends Number> T[] parseBulk(String bulk, Class<T> type) throws ParseException {
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(false);

    String[] elements = bulk.split(";");
    T[] result = (T[])Array.newInstance(type, elements.length);
    for (int i= 0; i< elements.length; i++)
        result[i] = (T)numberFormat.parse(itemElements[i]); // here it crashes
    //  result[i] = type.cast(numberFormat.parseObject(itemElements[i])); // does not work either
    return result;
}

...

Double[] shouldBeDoubles = parseBulk("15.5;10", Double.class);
```

Looks like Number determines resulting type by content of the String given, which yields a Double for "15.5" and a Long for "10".

Then it happily crashes trying to convert Long to T, which is Double.

Thank you,

**Update**: added numberFormat to the source code. Excuse me :)

Comment: What type does numberFormat have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumberFormat.parse(String source)` returns a `Number`. The runtime type of the returned instance can be any sub-class of `Number`, so if it returns a `Long`, you can't cast it to `Double`, as you learned.

If you want to force the numeric type that the `String`s will be converted to, you can pass a parser `Function` to the method:

```
static <T extends Number> T[] parseBulk(String bulk, Class<T> type, Function<String,T> parser) {
    String[] elements = bulk.split(";");
    T[] result = (T[])Array.newInstance(type, elements.length);
    for (int i= 0; i< elements.length; i++) {
        result[i] = parser.apply(elements[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And call it, for example, with:

```
Double[] shouldBeDoubles = parseBulk("15.5;10", Double.class,Double::valueOf);
```

This will output:

```
[15.5, 10.0]
```

Comment: What a beautiful somewhat-ugly solution. Requires Java 8 though :( I'm writing this for older Android, so a no go for me.

Comment: @Anton you can write something similar in Java 7, but it will require more code. You'll have to create some interface to use instead of `Function`, and you'll have to implement that interface with an anonymous class instance instead of a method reference.

Comment: It will be much less beautiful and much more ugly. I'd rather if-else them all in this case (which is a temporary solution that works for me right now). After all, there's not so many primitive numeric types in Java. Thanks anyways. I really enjoy the beauty and simplicity of your solution.